# Must match query is not working in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am tying to find all Videos with the name "The Shining"
but also with a parent_id = 189, and parent_type = "folder"

My query seams to connect all of the match statements with "OR" instead of "AND"

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "fields": ["name","parent_id","parent_type"],
  "query": {

    "and": {
      "must":[
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "The Shining"
          }
        },
        {
        "match": {
          "parent_id": 189
        }
      },
        {
          "match": {
            "parent_type": "folder"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
}
}
```

Mapping:

```
{"video" : {
"mappings" : {
  "video" : {
    "properties" : {
      "homepage_tags" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "metaType" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "tag_category_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "tag_category_order" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "tag_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "integer"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "parent_id" : {
        "type" : "integer"
      },
      "parent_type" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "provider" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "publish" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "query" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bool" : {
            "properties" : {
              "must" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "match" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "name" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                      },
                      "parent_id" : {
                        "type" : "long"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "source_id" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "subtitles" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "include_in_root" : true,
        "properties" : {
          "content" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "analyzer" : "no_stopwords"
          },
          "end_time" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "parent_type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "start_time" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "uid" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "video_id" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "video_parent_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "video_parent_type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "tags" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "content" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "end_time" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "metaType" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "parent_type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "start_time" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "uid" : {
        "type" : "integer"
      },
      "vid_url" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

Comment: Which version of ES you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by reading Volodymryrs answer above.

Aditional matches were being found because they were matching "the". I tried to add the operator argument, but that did not work unfortunately. What I did instead was to use "match_phrase" and also switched my two other match fields to "term" - see my answer below –

```
[
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'match_phrase' => [
                                'name' => $searchTerm
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'parent_id' => intVal($parent_id)
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'parent_type' => strtolower($parent_type)
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get matches on **the** or **shining** because of [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query, and depending on matches you will get score. One of the easiest fixes would be to add operator `and`:

```
{
   "match": {
      "name": "The Shining", 
      "operator": "and"
    }
}
```

But it's not what you need since this will also match names "shining The" or "The sun is shining".

Other option is that if you need to do exact matches on name, then you would need to make field **name** as non-analyzed. In ES 5 you can set field type as a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html)

In addition I would recommend you to use `bool` query with `term` queries since they will do exact match.

```
{
  "fields": ["name","parent_id","parent_type"],
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must":[{
              "term": {
                "name": "The Shining"
              }
            },
            {
            "term": {
              "parent_id": 189
            }
          },
            {
              "term": {
                "parent_type": "folder"
              }

            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about matches being found because they were matching "the".  I tried to add the operator argument, but that did not work unfortunately.  What I did instead was to use "match_phrase" and also switched my two other match fields to "term" - see my answer below